# batch file to match and rename multiple file names in a specified dir

Tags: batch-file

I need a script accomplish this mass rename file names.

From

```
C:\media\tv\How.I.Met.Your.Mother.S09E06.REPACK.HDTV.x2
C:\media\tv\The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E05.HDTV.x26
C:\media\tv\The.Blacklist.S01E01.HDTV.x26
```

To

```
C:\media\tv\How I Met Your Mother S09E06
C:\media\tv\The Big Bang Theory S07E05
C:\media\tv\The Blacklist S01E01
```

I already have a script:

```
dir /o:n/b "" >>Movie.txt
```

to pull and inventory of the tv folder and put it into a txt file. I just need to more or less modify that inventory (manually) and propagate the changes. 
something like if you find in column A change it to column B

A...........................................B

name.crap.cluTTER.............name

inventory..............................changed inventory

TIA for you help.

Comment: The file manager `Total Commander` has a `multi-rename` tool that can work across file trees and remove/change text, and also has `reg-exp` support if you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 q20492473.txt
 ) DO (
 SET fname=%%~nxa
 CALL :vername
 IF DEFINED fname (ECHO REN "%%a" "!fname!"
 ) ELSE (ECHO could NOT RENAME "%%~nxa")
)
GOTO :EOF
:vername
FOR /f %%i IN ("%fname%") DO SET fname=%%~ni&SET ext=%%~xi
IF NOT DEFINED ext SET "fname="&GOTO :EOF
IF /i NOT "%ext:~0,2%%ext:~4,1%%ext:~7,1%"==".SE" GOTO vername
SET num=9%ext:~2,2%%ext:~5,2%
FOR %%i IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO SET num=!num:%%i=!
IF DEFINED num GOTO vername
SET fname=!fname:.= ! %ext:~1%
GOTO :eof
```

This should get you started.

`q20492473.txt` is simply the name of a file I used as source text from your sample data. No doubt you could replace this with `'dir /a-d/b'` (including the single-quotes) if you wish.

---

Follow-up:

Ah - two important words here - "blah" and "flash". The `blah` is crucial since knowing what it is would aid in debugging (a few lines only - filenames that should have been renamed and some that shouldn't).

But the major flag waving is "flash" which indicates that you are attempting to run this code from the desktop by clicking on it.

I really believe that hiding people's mouses can force them to learn some fundamentals. It would also drive many insane.

Take your evil mouse and click Start>Programs>Accessories and then right-click on "Command Prompt". Select "Send To" and "desktop". This creates an icon which when clicked will open the black screen of enlightenment. Some are wont to call it "Command Prompt" but realists call it "DOS" since it's an emulator of MS-DOS. The conventional way to close this window is to type `EXIT`. You can set the size, font and colours used using the icon's "Properties" tab.

You would see a prompt; something like

```
c:\somedirectory>
```

which shows you the current or "logged" drive and directory.

You can change the logged drive by typing

```
x:
```

where `x` is your desired new driveletter.

You can change the logged directory by typing

```
cd "newdirectoryname"
```

where `newdirectoryname` is a directory relative to your current directory if it does NOT start with a `\` and absolute if it does. The quotes are optional - but best get used to using them because they MUST be used for some commands where the name (be it filename or directoryname) contains spaces.

You can change the directory in which you start by changing the starting directories in the properties for the icon.

At the prompt, you can get (sometimes obscure, often incomplete) documentation on a command by typing

```
commandname /?
```

so

```
dir /?
```

will show you the options available for the `dir` command.

So - I set up a directory on my `V:` drive ( a USB) called 'q20492473' and opened a dos window. I then typed

```
v:
cd "q20492473"
dir
```

and got this response:

```
 Volume in drive V has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 33C0-A799

 Directory of V:\q20492473

12/12/2013  11:41    <DIR>          .
12/12/2013  11:41    <DIR>          ..
12/12/2013  11:47               570 q20492473.bat
10/12/2013  20:24               416 q20492473.txt
12/12/2013  11:45                 0 How.I.Met.Your.Mother.S09E06.REPACK.HDTV
12/12/2013  11:45                 0 The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E05.HDTV
12/12/2013  11:45                 0 The.Blacklist.S01E01.HDTV
12/12/2013  11:45                 0 How.I.Met.Your.Mother.Sx9E06.REPACK.HDTV
12/12/2013  11:45                 0 The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07Ey5.HDTV
12/12/2013  11:45                 0 Thisisjustanormalfile
12/12/2013  11:45                 0 noextension
12/12/2013  11:45                 0 The.Big.Bang.Theory.S27E05.HDTV
12/12/2013  11:45                 0 This.&.That.Theory.S27E05.HDTV
10/12/2013  20:25               604 q20492473.bat.bak
              12 File(s)          1,590 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  51,678,806,016 bytes free
```

You'll note that q20492473.bat is in the list.

This is its content - it's identical to the above listing, except the `dir...` has been replaced

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /a-d/b'
 ) DO (
 SET fname=%%~nxa
 CALL :vername
 IF DEFINED fname (ECHO REN "%%a" "!fname!"
 ) ELSE (ECHO could NOT RENAME "%%~nxa")
)
GOTO :EOF
:vername
FOR /f %%i IN ("%fname%") DO SET fname=%%~ni&SET ext=%%~xi
IF NOT DEFINED ext SET "fname="&GOTO :EOF
IF /i NOT "%ext:~0,2%%ext:~4,1%%ext:~7,1%"==".SE" GOTO vername
SET num=9%ext:~2,2%%ext:~5,2%
FOR %%i IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO SET num=!num:%%i=!
IF DEFINED num GOTO vername
SET fname=!fname:.= ! %ext:~1%
GOTO :eof
```

Entering

```
q20492473
```

Resulted in a response

```
could NOT RENAME "q20492473.bat"
could NOT RENAME "q20492473.txt"
REN "How.I.Met.Your.Mother.S09E06.REPACK.HDTV" "How I Met Your Mother S09E06"
REN "The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07E05.HDTV" "The Big Bang Theory S07E05"
REN "The.Blacklist.S01E01.HDTV" "The Blacklist S01E01"
could NOT RENAME "How.I.Met.Your.Mother.Sx9E06.REPACK.HDTV"
could NOT RENAME "The.Big.Bang.Theory.S07Ey5.HDTV"
could NOT RENAME "Thisisjustanormalfile"
could NOT RENAME "noextension"
REN "The.Big.Bang.Theory.S27E05.HDTV" "The Big Bang Theory S27E05"
REN "This.&.That.Theory.S27E05.HDTV" "This & That Theory S27E05"
could NOT RENAME "q20492473.bat.bak"
```

because the only files that can be renamed according to the formula are those where the report line starts with `ren` (batch is largely case-insensitive). The others don't fit, so aren't renamed by the batch.

I've simply `ECHO`ed the `REN` command for verification purposes. Remove the `ECHO` keyword before the `REN` in `q20492473.bat` and the rename would be attempted when the batch is run.

Finally, `q20492473.bat` (or whatever you've called it) does not have to reside in the current directory. You could run it as `c:\wherever\you\have\stored\it\q20492473` if you like - remembering to `"quote the name"` if it contains spaces.

When presented with an executable name, batch will look in the current directory and then "along the path." until the excutable is found. The **PATH** is a series of <kbd>;</kbd>-separated directorynames contained in an environment variable called, bizarrely, **PATH**.

You can see what environment variables are set to by using

```
set
```

or specifically, since **PATH** is so important,

```
path
```

Many batchers create a special directory to contain batch files and other useful utilities. Popular names include `C:\batch` and `C:\belfry`. By including this directory in the **PATH** then *batchname* can be run regardless of your current directory.

Methods to modify **PATH** can be found in other responses on SO

Comment: thanks for the script. is the q20492473.txt the file that I have the two column of changes?
if not, then where is it that I input the nameA nameB? 
I'm still pretty new to reading these things so not really sure where user specific stuff goes verse what's parameters. 
thanks for the quick response to the original Q.

Comment: No. The filename has no significance - I just copied your source filename data to a file with that name. You named it `movie.txt`. I have a batch file that creates a skeleton and a text file and loads both into an editor. The name of the file is Q+the SO question number. Saves me mucho time. You could replace that filename with the `dir` command I mentioned in the last paragraph (including the single quotes) and it will then (ECHO) rename the files in the current directory.

Comment: I put the whole thing into a .txt (swapping in the 'dir'). then saved as a .bat in the dir I wanted to run it. upon double clicking it cmd flashes with this: "COULD NOT RENAME blah" repeated one line per file in the dir. and nothing is changed. is the fact that this is on an external HD a factor? I promise I'm trying hard, just not script savvy yet. also do I still need to run MY 'dir' script? or does putting YOUR 'dir' line in replace the need for that? Also your saying that your script polls an inventory and pulls it up in a box for me to make changes? TY for patience and help.
-Beau

Comment: after much toil my little IT brain finally figured it out. I got it to make the change. and I understand how to use it with and w/o the ECHO toggle.
turns out my mistake was in my test folder. none of the files in my test folder matched my example folder paths. but after using those it worked. so how do I use this script and apply it to an 800 file folder? thanks for your willingness to teach.

Comment: The script couldn't care how many files there are - it will process them all. If you leave the `ECHO` in place, then `scriptname >tempfile.txt` would produce a text file of what the script proposes to do. Probably easier than trying to read from the screen. When you've checked it, delete the `echo` keyword and run again.

Comment: I do that and the temp file gives me a tidy looking:
*****************************************************
could NOT RENAME "baasdfgt.txt"
could NOT RENAME "How I Met Your Mother S09E06"
could NOT RENAME "inventory.bat"
could NOT RENAME "inventory.txt"
could NOT RENAME "movies.txt"
could NOT RENAME "rename.bat"
could NOT RENAME "sdfasdfasdf.txt"
could NOT RENAME "tempfile.txt"
could NOT RENAME "The.last.mohican.1995.repak.xvid.txt"
************************************************
where do I make changes to that so that the script can make the changes to the rest of the files I need to rename?

Comment: None of the files mentioned can be renamed because the name does not fit the formula. The question is why did the `REN` lines not appear? Can only be one of two things: the `ECHO REN` is in place and no filenaes found fitted the formula, or `ECHO REN` has been replaced by `REN` - which should mean that the files **WERE** renamed according to the scheme. Have to rely on your observations...